i Am using azure appservice run from package by setting the url to use a blob WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE= <my blob url> but its not working
WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE = 
but site wont come up I have verified the blob URL its pointing properly to a zip file and even SAS key is proper but site wont come up in apperceive editor I see a txt file which says "Run From Package Initialization failed."


Share More details about the issue.

this is the file content   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
0   408    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 403

Share Appsettings of your AppService.

@PravallikaKV i have uploaded

Did you check if all the files uploaded in the App Service?

NO files are uploaded :( there is a text file in root which says "Run From Package Initialization failed"

Did you add the appsetting using command or manually?

Check if below solution helps @CodingPanda.

Follow below steps to deploy the webapp to Azure using WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE=<Blob_SAS_URL>.

Upload the Application's Zip file in the Storage container and generate the SAS URL.



Configure the WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE application setting to Storage Blob's SAS URL using the command:

az webapp config appsettings set --name ruklapp --resource-group ruk --settings WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACAGE="<Blob_SAS_URL>"

az webapp config appsettings set --name appname --resource-group rgname --settings WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACAGE="<Blob_SAS_URL>"

D:\a\_work\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/backend.py:17: UserWarning: You are using cryptography on a 32-bit Python on a 64-bit Windows Operating System. Cryptography will be significantly faster if you switch to using a 64-bit Python.
App settings have been redacted. Use `az webapp/logicapp/functionapp config appsettings list` to view.
[
  {
    "name": "APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING",
    "slotSetting": false,
    "value": null
  },
  {
    "name": "ApplicationInsightsAgent_EXTENSION_VERSION",
    "slotSetting": false,
    "value": null
  },
  {
    "name": "XDT_MicrosoftApplicationInsights_Mode",
    "slotSetting": false,
    "value": null
  },
  {
    "name": "WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACAGE",
    "slotSetting": false,
    "value": null
  }
]

I can see the deployed files in the KUDU site of the Azure App Service:

Response:


As said above there was a file generated by the name "Run From Package Initialization failed" and in that there was a content from curl command which was saying "403" which clearly stated an access issue on my blob . on further analysis i found that there are access configurations at container level also i allowed access to container and blob and then it started to work.
